# What might a time travel facility be called?

Tags: time-travel, transportation, infrastructure, names

In the real world one may catch a train at a station, a flight from an airport, a bus from a depot, a boat from a port or terminal.

If one were to travel through time inside a time machine what would one call the location from which scheduled departures and arrivals occur?

Some names I have mulled over include:

- Timeport
- Time station/temporal station
- Time interchange/hub
- Chronodrome

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding, please take a good read at our [help]. How to call something is entirely up to you, we prefer questions which can be answered in a more objective way

Comment: https://maniacmansion.fandom.com/wiki/Chron-O-John

Comment: I assume that by the time these are invented everyone will be calling them shíjiān chuánsòng mén.

Comment: @EveninginGethsemane should be 月光宝盒 they always based on mythology or classic, also is Google translate under maintenance or they boycotting ;D

Comment: As L.Dutch said, asking about choosing a name is off-topic; It's your work (in the art sense) and we're not here to steal you the joy of finding a name that suits it best :). If you lack word pieces to make that choice however, you could ask here. Although... Please note it's quite tricky to ask this kind of question, you'll have to see -and communicate- the nuances on top of clearly defining the objectives and context. See this [question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/224180/80336]) as an example (Note that it got closed and reopened).

Comment: Why all the "time-" name ideas? The bus station is called a bus station and not a space-station or a distance-station ;D!

Comment: @Daron It seems reasonable since we have `air-port`, `sea-port`, `space-port` already. We don't call it a `plane-station` after all.

Comment: @L.Duch is there a meta post or something on the help page or some other way a new user would know that this sort of question isn’t allowed? This is a pretty poor new user experience. This question doesn’t appear to me much more opinion based than most other questions on world building.

Comment: This question for example. There’s no obvious way (to me) that the chosen answer could be anything but the best one in the opinion of the asker. https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/224965/how-would-a-radar-work-while-inside-a-ftl-dimension

Comment: @alessandro The question you refered to is already with 3 votes to close out of 5, so it might not be the best example :D. A common reason to close for being opinion-based is the lack of criteria to choose a best answer, but you can find more about these kind of thing on meta worldbuilding SE. Or ask there on meta if you couldn't find anything

Comment: @Tortliena Well. I don't even have the privilege of viewing that information. All I can see is that OP is +14 and the top answer is +26. It's completely unclear to me why this q was closed: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/222186/why-are-orcs-always-at-war-for-seemingly-no-reason while this one is open:https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/215769/how-do-i-stop-annoyed-wizards-from-killing-people-all-the-time

Comment: @alessandro That's why I told you :). If you want to understand people's decisions, look or ask on [meta](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/). Here is not the place to do this.

Answer (score 1):

## It depends how the time machines work

Unlike the question and some comments assume, the etymology of transport infrastructure has only a little to do with the mode of transportation, and much more to do the the organisation of the transport network. Let me give you some examples.

### Timestation

This implies that your time machines operate on a fixed route, and are stopping along it, much like a train station or the predecessors of general trading stations. If i could catch a machine to today + or - 6 months, and that's all, it would probably be referred to as a station.

### Timedrome

This just implies a place where the time machines can depart and arrive. It says nothing else about the organisation of the transport network. It descends from the ancient Greek word for "course" and although it is predominately used for aircraft, it is also usable in the word "hippodrome" as in a course for horses. However, because most people have no need to go to a hippodrome or aerodrome, it is a somewhat archaic word, even though it fulfils a perfectly usable general description.

### Timestrip/Timefield

Implies time machines need a runway or field  to operate. That's really all it tells you.

### Timeport

This means your transport infrastructure requires a commercial port authority to run. If it requires a dedicated company to run it, and keep it organised, safe and functioning, it is probably going to be a larger facility, handling larger volumes of passengers, freight or both. In the case of airports, all airports are aerodromes, but not all aerodromes are airports, because the small ones don't need a full sized port authority to run.

### Timehub

Implies it's a central station that services many destinations

### Time Interchange

Implies it's infrastructure predominantly designed to facilitate passengers or freight switching from one transport mode/route to another.

In summary, you need to think about how your time machines work, and how they fit with a larger infrastructure. How are your passengers arriving, where are they going to, and how much organisation the whole setup needs. Once you have that, you can pick a sensible word.

Comment: Clarity note : The first part of each of the word you presented is still dependent of the machine or mean of transportation : Train interchange/time interchange, bus station/time station, timefield/airfield.... The "time" part can be "chrono", "clock", or any other word depending on the machine.

Answer (score -2):

**Brand/Proper Names**

In the future time travel is common. People rarely say anything like "time machine". Heck in the present people rarely say "car". They usually just say the brand or type of the car. For example "Red Nissan" or "White Sedan". These are both proper names. The first is the make of car and the second is named after Sedan in France.

[image]

In the future there are competing time travel companies. Their time machines are physically different.

The Wakefield and Sons machine is like a telephone cubicle that closes the door, shakes you up and down and then opens the door again. This is usually called a Wakefield Station or just a Wakefield for short. Some people call it a Hopper informally.

The ChronoVerse machine is a cart you strap yourself into. The cart travels around and around a circular track while a big gyroscope deely whirls around the track. This is called a Chronoverse Station, Chrono Stop, or just a Looper or Gyro.

The Meesa Inc time machine comes in a pill. You go to the Meesa Station or Pill Station. Some large pharmacies have it too.

Comment: A [*sedan*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedan_(automobile)) is not a brand of car, it is a *style* of car; namely, it is a three-box passenger automobile, with a box for the engine at the front, a box for the passengers in the middle and a box for the baggage at the back. It is also an American word; in English English, this kind of car is called a *saloon*. (In French, it is called a *berline*, which word was adopted in many European languages.)

Comment: @AlexP You are correct. It comes from Sedan chair which is named after a town in France.

Comment: The English word *sedan* in the sense of a small litter is attested in English from the 1634. I rather doubt that the town of Sedan in France was all that well known in England at that time; and anyway such chairs were not made there. (And it wasn't even in France; it was a small but independent principality. France only took it in 1642.)

Comment: @AlexP Next you will tell me invention of the chair was not named after my great uncle Chair.